# Compress command results in corrupted zip file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a script set up to rotate some log files in windows, and as part of the process I'd like it to automatically compress the rotated file. To do this I use the command

compress source.file destination.file.zip

However, if I try to open the file, I get the message "The Compressed (zipped) Folder is invalid or corrupted"

I've tried compress with -Z, and I get the same message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[compress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress) output is not [ZIP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) compatible, it uses the [LZW algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch).

The only way to "open" a `compress`ed file is with `uncompress` or [gunzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip).

Windows ports of common Unix commands, including `compress` and `gzip`/`gunzip` available [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

EDIT: To produce ZIP files from the command line in Windows, you can use something like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), which includes a command line application (`7z.exe`). The Unix commands linked above also include `zip.exe` for manipulating ZIP files from the command line.

Comment: The compress command does not do the same thing as the "send to: compressed (zipped) folder"? Is there a windows command that will do that?

Comment: @JuBu1324: No, the `compress` command (not sure where you even got it, Windows does not come with one) does not do the same thing as placing a file in a "compressed (zipped) folder" (which is just a `.zip` file). Download something like 7-zip (http://www.7-zip.org/) which includes a command line version (7z.exe) to produce ZIP files.

Comment: This isn't really the answer I was looking for, but since I like the unix option and it doesn't require any installation (which is important on for our servers right now), I'm going to mark this as the answer.